# pick a random number, always with increasing value over last random number picked

Tags: r, random, sample

How would I efficiently go about taking a 1-by-1 ascending random sample of the values 1:n, making sure that each of the randomly sampled values is always higher than 
the previous value?

e.g.:

> For the values 1:100, get a random number, say which is 61. (current list=61)
>   Then pick another number between 62 and 100, say which is 90 (current list=61,90)
>   Then pick another number between 91 and 100, say which is 100.
>   Stop the process as the max value has been hit (final list=61,90,100)

I have been stuck in loop land, thinking in this clunky manner:

```
a1 <- sample(1:100,1)

if(a1 < 100) {
    a2 <- sample((a+1):100,1)
        }

etc etc...
```

I want to report a final vector being the concatenation of a1,a2,a(n):

```
result <- c(a1,a2)
```

Even though this sounds like a homework question, it is not. I thankfully left the days of homework many years ago.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Coming late to the party, but I think this is gonna rock your world:

```
unique(cummax(sample.int(100)))
```

Comment: That is truly awesome! (I've never seen `cummax` before, clearly I've never bothered reading the help for `cumsum`)

Answer (score 6):

This uses a `while` loop and is wrapped in a function

```
# from ?sample
resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]

sample_z <-  function(n){
  z <- numeric(n)
  new <- 0
  count <- 1

  while(new < n){
    from <- seq(new+1,n,by=1)
    new <- resample(from, size= 1)
    z[count] <- new
    if(new < n)  count <- count+1
  }

  z[1:count]
}

set.seed(1234)

sample_z(100)
## [1]  12  67  88  96 100
```

## Edit

note the change to deal with when the new sample is 100 and the way `sample` deals with an integer as opposed to a vector for `x`

## Edit 2

Actually reading the help for `sample` gave the useful `resample` function. Which avoids the pitfalls when length(x) == 1

Comment: I'm getting some odd results with this code, where it sometimes hits 99 and starts at a lower point again. Looking into it...

Comment: Hmmm I see what you mean -- I will think about it!

Comment: Due to the way `sample` changes when `x` is a single integer not a vector - altered ( tested with 1e6 samples, no errors)

Comment: And now even better due to actually reading the help for sample

Answer (score 3):

Not particularly efficient but:

```
X <- 0
samps <- c()
while (X < 100) {
    if(is.null(samps)) {z <- 1 } else {z <- 1 + samps[length(samps)]}
    if (z == 100) {
        samps <- c(samps, z)
    } else { 
        samps <- c(samps, sample(z:100, 1))
    }
    X <- samps[length(samps)]
}
```

samps
EDIT: Trimming a little fat from it:

```
samps <- c()
while (is.null(samps[length(samps)]) ||  samps[length(samps)] < 100 ) {
    if(is.null(samps)) {z <- 1 } else {z <- 1 + samps[length(samps)]}
    if (z == 100) {
        samps <- c(samps, z)
    } else { 
        samps <- c(samps, sample(z:100, 1))
    }
}

samps
```

Comment: This one works ok, though it sometimes repeats the preceding value rather than going at least one more.

Comment: It shouldn't; about five minutes before you posted I made an edit that adds 1 each time.  I tested it on 100,000 repeats and never did it repeat the preceding value.

Comment: My apologies, I missed your stealth edit. All is well now it seems.

Answer (score 1):

even *later* to the party, but just for kicks:

```
X <- Y <- sample(100L)
while(length(X <- Y) != length(Y <- X[c(TRUE, diff(X)>0)])) {}
```

---

```
> print(X)
[1]  28  44  60  98 100
```

Answer (score 1):

### Sorting Random Vectors

Create a vector of random integers and sort it afterwards.

```
sort(sample(1:1000, size = 10, replace = FALSE),decreasing = FALSE)
```

Gives 10 random Integers between 1 and 1000.

```
> sort(sample(1:1000, size = 10, replace = FALSE),decreasing = FALSE)
[1]  44  88 164 314 617 814 845 917 944 995
```

This of course also works with random decimals and floats.